# Fastest way to pass function on all items in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of about 50,000 or so words, and I want to pass a function on each item in the list. Then I want to save the original word as a key, and the translated word as the respective value in a dictionary. Right now I know I can do this:

```
translations = {word: translate(word) for word in word_list}
```

But this takes too long I think. Is there a faster way this can be accomplished?

Comment: How do you anticipate it getting faster?

Comment: Not sure, just wondering. Right now it seems to take quite a while and I just thought there might be a more efficient way.

Comment: It's very likely that the majority of your time is spent inside of `translate`.

Comment: Have you tried the `map()` function?

Comment: can you see how much time translate(word) is taking for each word ? If its taking more time, so you might need to improve the code there.

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote the translate function, and it improved the speed greatly.

Comment: The lesson here is knowing what to optimize so you don't waste your time doing it to code that doesn't matter, which is fairly easy to do in Python — see [_How can you profile a Python script?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: You may consider profiling your code, to see where it spends its time. Try https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler et al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need few values, and won't iterate over the dict, you can try doing it lazily:

```
class MyDefaultDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, word_iterable, translate):
        self.word_set = frozenset(word_iterable)
        self.translate = translate
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if key in self.word_set:
            translated = translate(key)
            self[key] = translated
            return translated
        raise KeyError(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapping functions should work faster than dict comprehensions:

```
translations = dict(zip(word_list, map(translate, word_list)))
```

What happens here is:

- We apply the function to each element in `word_list`, returning a `map` object
- Combine it into a sequence (`zip` object) of one-to-one element tuples from the original list and that map object
- Convert the resulting sequence into a dictionary

After setting up a test program, it appears that there is a slight performance improvement. This is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
def translate(wo):
    return wo.upper()

word_list = {str(i):str(i+1) for i in range(50000)}
d = datetime.now()
translations = dict(zip(word_list, map(translate, word_list)))
print(datetime.now() - d)
d = datetime.now()
translations = {word: translate(word) for word in word_list}
print(datetime.now() - d)
```

After a few runs, the second printed time is always greater than the first one, which proves the efficiency.